# CircuitLab simulation of 555 timer - OUT HIGH always delivering 5V irrespective of Vcc?

Tags: timer, 555, mosfet-driver, circuitlab

I've scratched together a design for a 555 timer based driver for an IR540 MOSFET. But in CircuitLab the simulator shows the 555's OUT voltage is always 5V when high, for Vcc ranges 3.3V through 24V. That doesn't make much sense to me.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY9eCy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does anyone know what the actual part for the 555 modeled by CircuitLab is? I've read that some 555s do have clamped output voltage, but most deliver Vcc - ~ 1.7V.

Is the modelling weird or am I just doing something dumb?

[Crosslink: CircuitLab forum post](https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/modeling-and-simulation/topic/fwj6wp4a/555-modeling-simplistic-out-high-voltage-always-5v/#comment_8474)

[Related prior question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/442792/146535)

Comment: Sounds like a simulator bug.  Did you get 5V when using a 3.3 V supply too?

Comment: yes it looks like a bug, the same thing happens when I try. As a work-around  maybe use an amplifier to boost the signal to a sensible level.

Comment: @OskarSkog Yep I tried *"Vcc ranges 3.3V through 24V"*. So I think it's a magic part. CircuitLab doesn't simulate many ICs yet, and I guess it's rough around the edges. Amazing tool though.

Comment: Also thanks for the edig @Jasen . I couldn't get the StackExchange editor to accept an existing circuit URL when I tried, it just popped up the CircuitLabe editor for a new circuit.

Comment: cut and paste for the win.

Comment: @OskarSkog Care to post as answer?